# ag-grid filter panel customization

Tags: ag-grid

Wondering if anyone has customized ag-grid so that the filter panel is on the left (instead of right) with criteria open by default. We would like to improve usability by making the filters less obscure.

Also wondering if filter criteria can be added/removed by the user rather than having all criteria listed by default.

Answer (score 0):

There is `position` param thatse ts the side bar position relative to the grid.

```
sideBar = {
    toolPanels: [
        ...
    ],
    position: 'left',
    defaultToolPanel: 'filters'
}
```

Filter criteria can be also added/removed regarding your needs by defining your custom `toolPanel`:

```
var columnDefs = [
    { 
        field: "your_field",
        filter: false, //set filter to false to hide it from sidebar
    },
];
```

and the sidebar settings:

```
sideBar = {
        {
            id: 'filters',
            labelDefault: 'Filters',
            labelKey: 'filters',
            iconKey: 'filter',
            toolPanel: 'agFiltersToolPanel',
        }
    ]
}
```

More detail in official documentation: [ag-grid sidebar](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/)